# $(this).parent().find() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, wordpress-theming, this

I am making a Wordpress widget showing an image, and to upload/change this image I use the Wordpress media uploader.

This is the admin form markup I'm using:

```
<p class="media-control"
    data-title="Choose an image"
    data-update-text="Choose image">

    <input class="image-url" name="image-url" type="hidden" value="">

    <img class="image-preview" src=""><br>
    <a class="button" href="#">Pick image</a>
</p>
```

When I click ".media-control a" the uploader appears and I can pick an image. But when I've picked an image ".image-preview" and ".image-url" isn't updated.

Here's my javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/etzolin/DjADM/

Everything is working as intended except these lines:

```
jQuery(this).parent().find('.image-url').val(attachment.url);
jQuery(this).parent().find('.image-preview').attr('src', attachment.url);
```

When I write them like this, input value is set and image preview is updated:

```
jQuery('.media-control .image-url').val(attachment.url);
jQuery('.media-control .image-preview').attr('src', attachment.url);
```

But since I use more than one of these widgets it updates the input value and image preview in every widget.

How can I set the input value and update the image preview only in the widget I'm editing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please update your code **into some fiddle** or jsbin, codepen, ... we have many other sites much better than the so-called pastebin. Looks like pastebin limits access from some countries or regions, I can't access that site.

Comment: @king Sorry, here's a jsfiddle with the javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/etzolin/DjADM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the event handler for the media frame `this` is not the clicked element

```
var media_frame;

jQuery('.media-control a').live('click', function (event) {

    var self = this;

    event.preventDefault();

    if (media_frame) {
        media_frame.open();
        return;
    }

    media_frame = wp.media.frames.media_frame = wp.media({
        title: jQuery(self).parent().data('title'),
        button: {
            text: jQuery(self).parent().data('update-text'),
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    media_frame.on('select', function () {
        attachment = media_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        jQuery(self).parent().find('.image-url').val(attachment.url); // set .image-url value
        jQuery(self).parent().find('.image-preview').attr('src', attachment.url); // update .image-preview
        //      ^^ this is not the element from the click handler but the media frame
    });

    media_frame.open();
});
```

and you should be using `on()` as `live()` is deprecated and removed from jQuery

Comment: This works perfectly! I've been pulling my hair trying to find an answer all day. Thank you!